# Click on dynamic children DOMs with condition on parent class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have `.main` that contain a list of dynamic content that can be added on the fly. The `.main` can also be disabled with `.disable` class. When it's disabled, I don't want all the content items to be clicked.

You can see below that I am using a **hack** to detect `.disable` class after `.main` being clicked. Is there a way to **structure the CSS selector for jQuery** to avoid picking up children DOMs event if parent has certain class? Maybe some kind of `.main:not(.disable)` but I couldn't figure out how.

**Code:** http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/99rjU/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="state">Enabled</div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<a class="btn" href="#">
Toggle State
</a>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
    if ($('.main').hasClass('disable')) {
        $('.main').toggleClass('disable');
        $('.state').text('Enabled');
    } else {
        $('.main').toggleClass('disable');
        $('.state').text('Disabled');
    }
});

$('.main').on('click', ' ul li', function() {

    /* This is a hack
    if ($('.main').hasClass('disable'))
        return;
    */

    alert('Item is clicked');
});
```

I was thinking of other **unclean alternatives**:

1. Do whole `body` click event like this `$('body').on('click', '.main:not(.disable) ul li', function()` but this one is very ugly! It has to scan the whole body on each click
2. Unbind `li` click event each time `a` is trigger to call `disable`. But is this an optimal or best practice to do so?

**UPDATE 1**:

So actually in my project I only want to disable the `a` in the list. Since there are other `buttons` and `divs` that I still want to trigger event. However, look like using this won't work

```
.disable li a
{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Here is the link for this http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/99rjU/2/

Look like this is still experimental and won't work on anchor tag??

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: I don't see a problem with the check you have, but note that your comment on your other "unclean" alternative #1: *"It has to scan the whole body on each click"* No, it doesn't "scan" the whole body. It hooks the click on the `body` element and if the click occurs, it looks at the chain of elements the click passed through (which is probably only, what, three to 10?) starting with `e.target` and continuing up each `parentNode` until it reaches `body`. That happens in microseconds.

Comment: Alternative 1 is also not ideal in term of scoping

Comment: @ HP: You say "also", but again, the first issue isn't an issue. The scope thing *is*, of course, and I probably wouldn't do it for *that* reason. (BTW: If you have more than one `.main`, the hack's code is wrong. You'd want `$(this).closest(".main").hasClass("disable")` instead.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you could disable all click event's on the div when it has the class `.disable` with css:

```
.disable
{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

This way nothing inside the div is clickable.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/99rjU/1/)**

For IE it is somehow harder, as IE 10 and below doesn't support `pointer-events`. However a great article has been written on how to bypass this with a layer function: http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/

I hope this is what you mean.

Comment: Please see my update. `pointer-events: none;` doesn't seem to work with `a` tag!!?

Comment: That is because you have your jQuery click on your `<li>` element. You can disable this if you want. 
You can also change your jQuery code so it is only fired when hitting `<a>`. Tell me if this is what you want and i'll show an example. `pointer-events: none;` does work with anchors.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
    var main = $('.main');
    $('.state').text(main.hasClass('disable') ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled');
    main.toggleClass('disable');
});

$('.main').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
    if ($(this).parents('.main.disable').length) {
        // actually this is similar to your alternative#1
        return;
    }
    alert('Item is clicked');
});
```

What about this?